# Remove Nobody as senders name

Tags: php

I am using a webform (created by Web Form Builder). Once the form is submitted, a notification email is sent to my email address. Everything is working fine, except that Nobody is shown a the senders name.

The script is using a php configuration file like this:

```
"notification_message" : 
    {
        "bcc" : "",
        "cc" : "",
        "custom" : 
        {
            "body" : "Sample Form Notification\n\nFirst Name: [FirstName]\nLast Name: [Name]\nGender: [Gender]\nEmail: [Email]\nDOB: [Day] [Month] [Year]\nCountry: [Country]\nCity: [City]\nRegion: [Region]\nLanguages: [Languages]\nPhone: [Phone]\nSkype: [Skype]\nTime Zone: [TimeZone]\nTime spent on the Internet: [TimeOnInternet]\nSubmitted on: [_submitted_]\nIP Address: [_fromaddress_]\n",
            "is_present" : true,
            "subject" : "Local Representative Application"
        },
        "from" : "[Email]",
        "is_present" : true,
        "replyto" : "[Email]",
        "to" : "me@domain.com"
    }
```

The php mailer version is 5.1.

Any help how to add the [FirstName] to the from as a prefix to the email address is very much appreciated.

Comment: nothing to do with php, and everything to do with your mail server's configuration.

Comment: Understood, can you please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment is incorrect about nothing to do with php.

PHP sets a SMTP header for the "From" field and it needs to be in the format of:
`First Name <email@domain.com>`

Try setting from field to this:
`"from" : "First Name <email@usersdomain.com>"`
Note that the PHPMailer project does not have good documentation on this so you might want to ask your question about how to set the from field properly with the plugin code developers.